# How to export break line '\n' in a file using MySQL INTO OUTFILE

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to export a sql file using MySQL. I use this method because I want to import files with the `LOAD DATA` function. And the file name must be dinamically generated. I will execute the file generated throught the command line.

This is the script:

```
SET @filename = 'C:/icl/myfile.CSV';

SET @str = CONCAT('LOAD DATA INFILE ',@filename);
SET @str = CONCAT(@str,' INTO TABLE icl_process_data.filecontent LINES TERMINATED BY ''\n''');

SELECT @str INTO OUTFILE 'C:/icl/tmp_script.sql';
```

This is the result:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE C:/icl/myfile.CSV INTO TABLE icl_process_data.filecontent LINES TERMINATED BY '\'
```

I don't know why the result of the break line '\n' is '\'. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Don't forget to upvote, downvote, accept any answers with the Green checkmark whose ever it is if appropriate. That is our feedback for our efforts.

Answer (score 0):

It is a question of escape sequences and there are several ways to do it. I chose just putting the starting single quote nestled inside the outer double quotes near the end of the first way (with 3 chunks in `concat`).

And single quotes as the second way (with 2 chunks in `concat`):

```
SET @filename = 'C:/icl/myfile.CSV';
-- C:/icl/myfile.CSV

SET @str = CONCAT('LOAD DATA INFILE ',@filename);
-- LOAD DATA INFILE C:/icl/myfile.CSV

-- First way is below (with the result being the line after it if you ignore the `-- ` at the beginning):
SET @str = CONCAT(@str," INTO TABLE icl_process_data.filecontent LINES TERMINATED BY '","\\n'");
-- LOAD DATA INFILE C:/icl/myfile.CSV INTO TABLE icl_process_data.filecontent LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

-- Second way is below (with the result being the line after it if you ignore the `-- ` at the beginning):
SET @str = CONCAT('LOAD DATA INFILE ',@filename);
SET @str = CONCAT(@str,' INTO TABLE icl_process_data.filecontent LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\'');
-- LOAD DATA INFILE C:/icl/myfile.CSV INTO TABLE icl_process_data.filecontent LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

From the mysql manual page on [String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html):

[image]